# If $S$ is symmetric positive definite and $SA$ symmetric, is then $A$ symmetric?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

We are given real matrices $S$ and $A$. We know that $S$ is symmetric positive definite and that $SA$ is symmetric. Is A necessarily symmetric then?

I've figured out that if $A$ is symmetric, then $S$ and $A$ must commute. I've tried finding a $2 \times 2$ and a $3 \times 3$ counterexample, as it seemed to me that this is not generally true, but I couldn't find any.

Comment: Is $S$ also assumed symmetric?

Comment: @BartMichels Yes. I will add that to my question.

Comment: Start by finding a symmetric positive definite $S$ and symmetric $B$ that don't commute.  Then let $A=S^{-1}B$.

Comment: Yes, following O.Peters suggestion, you can ''easily'' find a counterexample. He's $B$ is yours $SA$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $S = \begin{bmatrix}2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, $A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1/2 \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$. Then $SA = \begin{bmatrix}2 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$ is symmetric, but $A$ is not.